# Getting a BadMethodCallException 'does not exist for function in model, but method exists

Tags: laravel

I wrote a method in the Order model that kept getting an error.

> Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::generateOrderCode does not
>   exist.

Even though it was almost the same as another method, generateCode() a method from a different model worked perfectly to find when called in the same way. I then made a test method, and I couldn't get it to work. I put all models in a separate folder and namespaced them, which works fine.

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    public function testFunction()
    {
        return ("success!");
    }
}
```

And then in the OrderController or Tinker:

```php
$order = new Order;
dd($order->testFunction());
```

Gives me

> Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::testFunction does not exist.

I've also done `composer dumpautoload` (if that would help anything) and even deleted the model and made a blank one with `php artisan make:model Order.`

I don't get it.

Comment: Have you try to do this in other controllers? you get the same error?

Comment: Other controllers are working just fine. In fact the function that I first had this problem with was copied straight out of another Model.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an instance of wrong class.

Check if `$order` is an actual instance of `Order` model, or some other class using `instanceof`:

```
 return ($order instanceof App\Models\Order); //should return true
```

Also, check from which file your class has been defined using `ReflectionClass` and its method `getFileName()`:

```
$refClass = new \ReflectionClass('App\Models\Order');

echo ($refClass->getFileName());
```

See more about Type Operators:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php

See more about ReflectionClass:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

Comment: Yes that returns true. That's bad right, because that's not what's causing it.

Comment: @Stroomschok, check my edited answer. You can use these 2 approaches in the future to avoid such issues. First to check correct instance, and second to check from what file Class is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Ok do I feel silly now. I solved it. Apparently a long time ago I already made an Order model, then decided not to use it and simply set it aside in a different folder. It was conflicting with the newly created Order model.

Comment: so it was actually wrong instance as I have mentioned